# Convert Java object methods call results to Clojure map

Tags: java, clojure

I'm new to Clojure and have created a simple macro to call certain methods on a Java class and return results into a Clojure map and this all works fine.  (Also i'm aware of the `bean` function however the classes I'm using aren't beans).

My question is in regard to the calling code.  Is it better form to pass the Java 'methods' as symbols?

I'm not even sure what type `.toString` is at the moment (in the calling code)? It all works but not sure its idiomatic Clojure.

```
(defmacro obj-to-map 
  [obj & body]
  (let [afn (fn [[method kw]]
              `(~kw (~method ~obj)))]
  `(assoc {} ~@(mapcat afn (partition 2 body)))))

(obj-to-map "hello" .length :length .toString :value)  

=>  {:value "hello", :length 5}
```

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/ngrunwald/gavagai would be helpful as well.

Comment: Yeah saw this project but its probably overkill for what I need. Its also fun to work these things out for yourself sometimes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.toString` etc are symbols in the calling code.

I think it would be better to pass the method name and invoke it using ".".

```
(defmacro obj-to-map 
  [obj & body]
  (let [afn (fn [[method kw]]
              `(~kw (. ~obj ~method)))]
  `(assoc {} ~@(mapcat afn (partition 2 body)))))

(obj-to-map "hello" length :length toString :value)  

=>  {:value "hello", :length 5}
```

Comment: You're right, that looks a lot nicer. "http://clojure.org/java_interop#Java Interop-The Dot special form"

Answer (score 0):

As an option consider solving this without macros. A macro would still implicitly use reflection, and here it is enough to apply `clojure.lang.Reflector/invokeInstanceMethod`

The basic implementation is `obj-to-map` followed by to simple modifications with var-args.

```
; just a reusable object for calling no-arg methods
(def empty_array (into-array Object []))

; function update-vals available since v1.11.50
(defn obj-to-map [obj methods]
  (update-vals methods
               #(clojure.lang.Reflector/invokeInstanceMethod
                  obj % empty_array)))

(defn obj-to-map2 [obj & methods]
  (obj-to-map obj (apply hash-map methods)))

(defn obj-to-map3 [obj & methods]
  (obj-to-map obj (into {} (for [k methods] [(keyword k) k]))))
    
(defn obj-to-map4 [obj & methods]
  (obj-to-map obj (into {} (for [k methods] [(keyword k) (str k)]))))

; usage

(obj-to-map "hello" {:len "length" :st "toString"})     ; => {:len 5, :st hello}

(obj-to-map2 "hello" :len "length" :st "toString")      ; => {:st hello, :len 5}

(obj-to-map3 "hello" "length" "toString")               ; => {:length 5, :toString hello}

(obj-to-map4 "hello" 'length 'toString)                 ; => {:length 5, :toString hello}
```

Docs: [update-vals](https://cljs.github.io/api/cljs.core/update-vals)